# Powerline Expecting ',' delimiter: line 55 column 6 (char 4037) error

Tags: powerline

[image: Error image]

I'm using powerline, bash, and iterm2 on mac. I also installed gitstatus, but that didn't work when I installed it two days ago, and powerline worked just fine yesterday without gistatus functioning. Today, when I booted up the terminal, this error showed instead of the prompt.

Any advice? Where can I find the full log of the errors/interpret this message? Alternatively, how can I pinpoint which file has an error on line 55?

Comment: Were you able to solve this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error was in a color config file for the github integration. I was missing a comma at between lines. I believe it was in this file  `.config/powerline/colorschemes/default.json` or another json related to it; see [here.](https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/powerline-gitstatus#configuration)

Ultimately, I recommend moving to powerlevel10k. You can configure it to look exactly like powerline, but it a) updates cleanly (compared to powerline where if you update your python it breaks horribly) and b) comes with a really good customization setup and c) lets you use zsh + oh-my-zsh which gives so much additional functionality